# I want to change the color

Tags: php, colors

I want help in modifying this code, as I want to add a color to these three names
**TIME** & **Date** & **day**

```
    <?php
        date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Cairo");
        // فرق التوقيت Tunis
        echo "TIME :  " . date("h:i:sa").
        "<br>"; // مسافه
        echo "Date :  " . date("Y/m/d").
        "<br>";
        echo "day :  " . date("l")
    ?>
```

Comment: You mean this: <span style='color:green;'>TIME</span>

Comment: You must use css. `<dive class="date"></div>`

Comment: PHP doesn't have a concept of colors when you output strings since it's a backend language (server side). If you want to add any styling, you need to add the correct HTML and/or CSS to the outputted string (which is what is returned to and rendered by the client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Cairo");
    // فرق التوقيت Tunis
    echo "<span style='color:red;'>TIME</span> :  " . date("h:i:sa").
    "<br>"; // مسافه
    echo "<span style='color:purple;'>Date</span> :  " . date("Y/m/d").
    "<br>";
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>day</span> :  " . date("l")
?>
```